# CRM 4: Retrieving email records (including to, from & cc partylist values)

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am trying to retrieve a list of emails for contact that meet a certain criteria (have simplified the number of conditions to keep it as simple as possible), but am struggling to work out how to pull out the Guids of PartyList fields (e.g. from, to & cc).  Here's the code that I have writen...

```
        string fetchXml = @"
                            <fetch mapping='logical'>
                                <entity name='email'>
                                    <attribute name='subject'/>                             
                                    <attribute name='regardingobjectid'/>
                                    <attribute name='from'/>
                                    <attribute name='to'/>
                                    <attribute name='prioritycode'/>
                                    <attribute name='statuscode'/>
                                    <attribute name='modifiedon'/>
                                    <attribute name='activityid'/>
                                    <order descending='false' attribute='subject'/>
                                    <link-entity name='contact' alias='ag' to='regardingobjectid' from='contactid'>
                                        <filter type='and'> 
                                            <condition attribute='examplecondition' value='1' operator='eq'/> 
                                            <condition attribute='anotherexamplecondition' value='5' operator='eq'/>
                                        </filter>
                                    </link-entity>
                                </entity>
                            </fetch>";

        XDocument document = crmService.ToXDocument(contactEmailfetchXml);


        var results = document.Root.Elements("result").Select(e =>
            new Email
                {
                    ActivityId = e.Element("activityid").ToGuid(),
                    Subject = e.Element("subject").Val(),
                    //From = e.Element("from").Val(),
                    //To = e.Element("to").Val(),
                    //CC = e.Element("cc").Val(),
                    PriorityCode = e.Element("prioritycode").Val()
                }).ToList();
```

And the 'Val' extension method is just:

```
    public static string Val(this XElement element)
    {
        return element != null
            ? element.Value
            : String.Empty;
    }
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.